# Xcode Button Image Not Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am new to Xcode and was wondering why my button is not displaying my image when building the application.

[image]

Comment: Make sure the name of the image is not changed in your attribute inspector.

Comment: how would I know pls? Thanks

Comment: you may be having issues with subview layout. try using "Debug View Hierarchy" to find the frames of all the UIButtons you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your storyboard, select your UIImageView, now in the Attributes Inspector check the name of the Image, if it is correct or not.

Check the screenshot

[image]

**EDIT**

You image folder is added as reference, while adding the folder make sure you have checked `Copy Items if Needed` and Create Groups, check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: make sure while building you are not getting any error of png crush.

Comment: the build is always successful.. it only happens when i add and image... because a button with no image always work

Comment: Are you using images from assets ?

Comment: You image folder is added just as a reference just try to add that folder again after deleting this one and make sure it is copied to your project

Answer (score 1):

You should put your images within the assets folder. Then it can stretch to the correct size you need.